# Remove millisecond from epoch-time/timestamp | java

Tags: java, timestamp, unix-timestamp, epoch

I have with me an epoch time, which i would like to convert to an sql timestamp. I can extract the actual time from the epoch using this code :

```
String time = "1351504294";
long t = Long.parseLong(time);
Timestamp ts = new Timestamp(t*1000);
```

The output I'm getting is : `2012-10-29 09:58:50.0`.
But when i  try to insert this into a table, it shows error because of the millisecond part, '09:58:50.0'. How can I remove the millisecond part from the timestamp?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are adding the `Timestamp` directly to the SQL statement then Java is calling the `toString()` function wich always outputs the format `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.fffffffff`. There is nothing that you could do to the `Timestamp` object that would eliminate the nanoseconds part.

If you want just the `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss` portion you could either do:

```
Timestamp ts = new Timestamp(t*1000);
String s = ts.toString().split('\\.')[0];
```

Or you could use `SimpleDateFormat`:

```
Timestamp ts = new Timestamp(t*1000);
String s = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss").format(ts);
```

Comment: That worked like charm. I used the second one. 1000 thanks :))

Comment: ..of which, on my hardware, the former takes roughly `0.9µs` and the latter `3.6µs` :)

Comment: Your "yyyy-mm-dd" text should be "yyyy-MM-dd"

Comment: Thanks. I tried `ts.toString().split('.')` before stumbling on your answer. Does anyone know why splitting the timestamp string only works with `\\.` but not `.`. I understand that `\\` is sometimes used for escaping but this doesn't help me understand it's use here.

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way....

```
public class Time {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        String time = "1351504294";
        long t = Long.parseLong(time);
        Timestamp ts = new Timestamp(t*1000);

        String date = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-dd hh:mm:ss").format(ts);
        System.out.println(date);
    }
}
```